# Geometry Nodes : capture the "Start & End Mapping" factors values from a curve object

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves

I'm working on an animation with curves, using curve trimming.

I do my animation drafts using the Start & End Mapping factors for the curve object, but in the end I would like to use Geometry Nodes and the Trim Curve Node (because I want also to add other effects in the process).

Rather than animating all the stuff twice (both using the Start & End Mapping factors, and the Trim Curve node), is it possible to retrieve the values of the Start & End Mapping within Geometry Nodes ?
Thanks !

Comment: Can we ask why you're not using Geometry Nodes from the get-go? Is it quicker, in your case, to use the Mapping-Factors?

Comment: I use the mapping factors as a "draft" before starting to use GN.

Comment: Okydoky, just curious... since GN is a modifier, I would have thought it offered non-destructive drafting in its own right. A simple ' Trim (fac_start, fac_end) ' group, copied between curves... (which could also stash fac_start, fac_end on the geometry, if needed)